# Unable to get data from parent process to child process

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I am using a Python3 program to create two processes: the child born out of the parent process. Everything starts with the parent process. The motive is to start a process, give it the live sensor data, and end it when the sensor reading passes a certain threshold.

The `sensor_data` is obtained through a thread in the parent process as:

```py
t = Thread(target=dump_sensor_data,args=())
t.start()
```

And I have tested that the live data can be used in any function as

```py
while True:
    global sensor_data
    print(sensor_data)
```

The child process is defined as:

```py
def fa():
    global sensor_data
    while sensor_data>300:
        print(f'I am printing {sensor_data} from fa')
        time.sleep(0.7)
```

I start it as:

```py
processes_list=[]
pa=Process(target=fa, args=())
pa.start()
processes_list.append(pa)
```

Now, I create another watch-guard function that kills the child process `fa()` as soon as the `sensor_data` exceeds 300.

```py
def watchguard():
    global sensor_data
    while True:
        print(lidar1)
        if sensor_data > 300:
            for p in processes_list:
                print(f'terminating process {p}')
                p.terminate()
                p.join()
                return
```

But this is what happens

```
0
terminating process <Process(Process-1, started)>
```

The `0` is the wrong value of `sensor_data` which I have verified and should be above 1000. Also, this leads to the process getting killed.

Why is the data not getting passed to this child process ?

Comment: you are saying "Exceeds 300" but your if clauase is saying if sensor_data is lower than 300, then terminate all processes in process_list ..

Comment: Its a typo. Sorry. I will correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it.

As Python multiprocessing does not allow global variables to be passed between processes, the variable was never sent or updated. This is not the case with multithreading.